# Not sure what the SYSTEM drive is doing on my second hard drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, backup

I had a major crash last year and had to reinstall the system (windows 10) I made an extra copy of the system even though it would not boot (due to a windows update) and reinstalled all the programs etc. copied over the data that I needed. I think I did a recovery install -- it was dual booting last year and I stopped that somehow.

**The bottom line** is that I want to do a full backup now and this is what my system looks like with Disk 0 powered/unpowered.

[image: DiskMgmt]
[image: DiskMgmt]

It will boot with just DISK 1 powered - and I just want the data on that disk and would like to finally clear off the other disk for just storage. 
But I and very paranoid about wiping that disk since its the only disk that says SYSTEM E: (?)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text in bold is **not** a usage description – it is the user label that you can set by "renaming" the disk within the 'My Computer' window. So it says "SYSTEM" here because someone named/labelled the disk "SYSTEM". That's it.

The actual usage description is the 3rd line, which says "(Boot)" for the partition containing the currently running Windows system, and either "(System)" or "(EFI System Partition)" for the partition containing files necessary to start Windows (i.e. the boot menu and bootloader).

---

It *is* possible (or at least was in WinXP days) that the system would boot from the new disk, but assign C: to the old disk and continue reading system files from there. But at least in your examples, that isn't the case.

Comment: Yea this is what I came to say. This is probably the naming from when the system was originally set up